# How to use ApplicationStateModel class of .net Metro style app?

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro

I want to save the application state when an metro style app receive the suspend event.

I found in [this link](http://dailydotnettips.com/2011/11/04/application-state-suspension-and-termination-of-apps-in-winrt) the code below, but I don´t find in .Net the class ApplicationStateModel:

```
public App()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   this.Suspending += new SuspendingEventHandler(App_Suspending);
   this.Resuming += new Windows.UI.Xaml.EventHandler(App_Resuming);
}

void App_Resuming(object sender, object e)
{
   // Write code to update ui only for items that are outdated.
   // This is resume from suspended state, so it does not lose any data
}

async void App_Suspending(object sender, Windows.ApplicationModel.SuspendingEventArgs e)
{
   // Write code to store data so that when the application is terminated the state can be recovered.
   // Allowed only 5 seconds to do the storage
   SuspendingDeferral deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
   await **ApplicationStateModel**.SaveAllApplicationDataAsync();
   await ApplicationStateModel.SaveSessionStateAsync();
   deferral.Complete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Windows.Storage.ApplicationData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.aspx) to save local settings.
Take a look at the [Sample SDK app](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ApplicationData-sample-fb043eb2) for a running app that saves your settings.